# Pear System_Command

Tags: pear

I am currently in my first day of `pear` programming, and was wondering what `system_command` does, and how to use it. What programming language does it execute, and where does it execute it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [System_Command](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Command) one can execute shell commands, like one would do with system and escapeshellargs, but with a clean OOP Interface.

[System_Command](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Command) is an unmaintained PEAR Package and returns PEAR errors instead of throwing Exceptions.

System_Command Methods:

- execute
- isError
- pushCommand - Used to push a command onto the running command to be executed
- pushOperator
- reset - Prepare for a new command to be built
- setOption

[Example](https://github.com/pear/System_Command/blob/master/docs/test.php)

[API Docs](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Command/docs/latest/)

Comment: Thanks allot! That explains it very well!